# How does NSUndoManager.groupsByEvent determine the current run loop pass?

Tags: cocoa, foundation, nsrunloop, cfrunloop

I'd like to understand/replicate the "group by run loop pass/cycle" feature of `NSUndoManger`:

`NSUndoManager` can group multiple calls to `registerUndo()` into a single "undo" operation when invoked multiple times on the same run loop cycle. This is determined by `NSUndoManager.groupsByEvent`, which is set to `true` by default.

So something like this:

```
// User clicks button... (causes a new run loop event)
undoManager.registerUndo(...) // #1
undoManager.registerUndo(...) // #2
```

...results in one undo group and clicking *Edit → Undo* reverts both changes at once.

Somehow NSUndoManager can figure out if two calls to `registerUndo()` are on the same run loop cycle. How does this work?

**My use case:**

I have code that sends property change notifications after the user interacts with the UI (e.g. clicks a button). There can be one or more events as the result of a user action. I'd like to group those and update the UI only once at the end of the current run loop.

Comment: "By default undo groups are begun automatically at the start of the event loop". `NSUndoManager` calls `beginUndoGrouping` if you didn't. Could you tell a bit more about your use case? What do you mean by "one or more events as the result of a user action"? How do you update the UI, `reloadData`, `setNeedsDisplayInRect`, draw something?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't want to get into the specifics about how or why I update the UI. First and foremost I'm curious to understand what's happening behind the scenes. Essentially I want to batch multiple calls to a method within one run loop cycle. Another example would be to debounce the calls and only consider the very last one per run loop cycle (triggered by a single user interaction).

Answer (score 1):

> NSUndoManager normally creates undo groups automatically during the run loop. The first time it is asked to record an undo operation in the run loop, it creates a new group. Then, at the end of the loop, it closes the group.

source: [Undo Operations and Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000205-74904)

`NSUndoManager` is part of the same framework as `NSRunLoop` so maybe `NSRunLoop` signals `NSUndoManager` to close a group. You don't know and you shouldn't want to know.

Comment: "Then, at the end of the loop, it closes the group.", but exactly how does it know when the run loop ends? I do want to know, because I'm curious and I  might learn something useful along the way.

Comment: `-[NSUndoManager endUndoGrouping]` is called in `+[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings]` which is called in `-[NSApplication run]`.